# Linux kernel code segment memory page modifications

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, xen

I'm trying to implement a "Semantic based memory sharing model" for Xen. As a part of my project, i'm trying to share kernel code pages across VMs. I' ve assumed that the code segments of linux kernels with similar version are 100% identical. But when i carry out some experiments using Virtual Machines running Debian Squeeze, i have found 3 memory pages are different in kernel code segment.

So my question is that, does the linux kernel modifies its code pages at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can - for example, spinlocks can be dynamically patched out of the code if the kernel sees at runtime that it is running on a uniprocessor system.  I do not know of an exhaustive list of such cases, you will need to inspect the code.

See the [LWN article on SMP Alternatives](http://lwn.net/Articles/164121/) for more information on one system that does runtime patching within the kernel.